# Initiating FullScreen on a VueJS/Quasar app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I need to instantiate the app so that it mounts and refreshes in fullscreen. There is a toggle button to exit it and a setting to turn it off (eventually). But for the time being I need it to load fullscreen. I did the following, but it seems to work whenever it feels like it lol. What gives!!! When it does load in fullscreen, and I turn it off, it doesn't reload in fullscreen on a refresh. Almost as if it is cashed in a local storage or something like that (** I can't inspect the docs in quasar since their website seems to be down at the moment)

```
import { AppFullscreen } from 'quasar'

export default {
  mounted () {
     this.toggleFullscreen()
  },
  methods: {
     toggleFullscreen () {
        AppFullscreen.toggle()
     }
  }
}
```

The toggleFullScreen is attached to a click event on an icon button that turns it off and on after the initial load